# How do I print the values in the groovy function?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am new to `groovy`. I am trying to print the vales in the function. But, I am unable to see in the logs. I would like to know if this is the right way to `echo` the values. Below is the code:

```
void kubernetesDeploy(String chartName, String imageTag, String kubecliVersion, String mavenChartName) {
    
        helloApplyHelmTemplate(
                env: "dev",
                chartName: "${chartName}",
                pathToValues: "./${chartName}/values-dev.yaml",
                imageTag: "${imageTag}",
                kubecliVersion: kubecliVersion,
                mavenChartName: "${mavenChartName}"
        )

            // Printing the variables for testing
            println "chartName:++++++ ${chartName}"
            println "pathToValues:++++++ ${pathToValues}"
            println "imageTag:++++++ ${imageTag}"
            println "kubecliVersion:++++++ ${kubecliVersion}"
            println "mavenChartName:++++++ ${mavenChartName}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong using the curly brackets to add strings within a print.

I'm not sure about your first bit of code, but if you mean formatting the code better I like using `padLeft`, `padRight`, and `center`. Everything is tidier with them.

Try you code like below:

````
void kubernetesDeploy(String chartName, String imageTag, String kubecliVersion, String mavenChartName) {

    // Printing the variables for testing
    println "chartName:".padRight(20) + chartName
    println "imageTag:".padRight(20) + imageTag
    println "kubecliVersion:".padRight(20) + kubecliVersion
    println "mavenChartName:".padRight(20) + mavenChartName

}


kubernetesDeploy("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4")```
````

Answer (score 0):

println don't writes in a log (BTW: which IDE are you using?) but writes to the output stream. In Eclipse it would be the Console View, in a shell the command prompt.